# Is there any method to download all the content of etc directory

Tags: directory

Today i deleted accidentally the content of my `etc/*` direcory with `sudo rm -rf` is there any website to download `etc/*` files from the net

Ps : i didn't reboot the computer till now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the `/etc` directory.

Just boot from Ubuntu live disk and copy the `/etc/` directory (live disk) to the `/etc` directory (in the partition where Ubuntu is installed)

```
sudo mkdir /media/os
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /media/os   # Mounting the root partition on /media/os directory.
sudo cp -Ri /etc/default /media/os/etc
sudo umount /dev/sdaX
```

Shutdown and boot from your Hard-disk.

Since the `/etc' directory contains all configuration files, it is better to start again from scratch, ie reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: The `/etc` directory consists of configuration files. So, I believe it is not possible to download them as those files vary with user and packages installed.

Comment: Correct. For that reason is better to reinstall the Operating System, rather than copy it from the live CD(imho).